# The navigation property is not a declared property on type. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Usually, for such cases there is a messup in the declaration of Foreign Keys but I have run my eyes over this code countless times.
Manifests and BL are parent-child entities.

```
Namespace models
Public Class manifest
    <DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)>
    <Key>
    Public Property id As Integer 'uses SQL sequence and not autogenerated
    Public Property arrivalDate As Date
    Public Overridable Property BL As IEnumerable(Of bl)
    Public Overridable Property Vessel As vessel
 end Class
End Namespace
```

And also

```
Namespace models

Public Class bl
    <DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)>
    <Key> <Column(Order:=2)>
    Public Property blid As Integer 
    <Key> <Column(Order:=1)>
    <ForeignKey("manifest")>
    Public Property manifestid As Integer
    <ForeignKey("manifestid")>
    Public Overridable Property manifest As manifest
    <Required>
    Public Overridable Property container As IEnumerable(Of container)
End Class
End Namespace
```

But in the end, the outcome is  **"The navigation property 'BL' is not a declared property on type 'manifest'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property."**

Any hint on what am I missing?

Comment: EF does not support `IEnumerable(Of T)` navigation properties. The minimum is `ICollection(Of T)` and derived.